# Lex and YACC (FLEX and Bison)

Tags: bison, yacc

Hello I need to understand flex and bison in order to rewrite to QRegExp the following question arose.
If the token is suitable for several teams at once, then how will YACC / BISON act?
For example, there is a FLOAT_NUM token,
there are two commands:

- the first one needs two tokens (STARTED and FLOAT_NUM)

  ```
   title: STARTED FLOAT_NUM
      {
       .
       .
       .
      }
  ```
- the second command only needs the FLOAT_NUM token

  ```
    my_type: FLOAT_NUM
       {
        .
        .
        .
       }
  ```

Accordingly, the following expression comes to YACC/Bison:

```
STARTED FLOAT_NUM
```

Am I correct in understanding that only the 'title' command will work, and the 'my_type' command will work only when one FLOAT_NUM arrives and nothing else?

Comment: `LR` parsing is strictly left-to-right; it doesn't search inside the input. But a full explanation requires a chapter in a textbook, which is far too much to expect from a SO answer. It would be far better to ask a concrete question about what you are actually doing, which might be possible to answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yacc generates a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that takes one token at the time and decides on the next state based on the current state and the token.

For example, in your case, if it get token `STARTED` it probably goes into a state that could be described as "I am in the terminal `title` at the position `1` and I expect token `FLOAT_NUM` now".
To answer the question what happens if a token `X` arrives, you always need to first know in which state the parser is currently.

It's hard to work with an incomplete example, so I'll assume your complete program looks like this:

```
%token STARTED FLOAT_NUM

%start main

%%

main: title | my_type {}
title: STARTED FLOAT_NUM {}
my_type: FLOAT_NUM {}
```

Parsing starts at the beginning of the start terminal (`main` in this case) and it ends when it reaches the end of the start terminal.

So, in this case the start terminal can consist of either `title` or `my_type`, so the parser expect that the first token is either `STARTED` or `FLOAT_NUM`.
When it gets either of them, the parser can unambiguously know if it is currently in `title` or `my_type`. If the example would be different and they started with the same token, the parser would just go into a state "either `title` or `my_type`, give me second token now" and the parsing would continue.

You can see what are all the generated states and how they change into each other, by running `bison` with the option `-r all` which creates a human-readable file with a complete report of the generated state machine.

That are the complete basics. I hope it helped.

If this isn't enough, I suggest to read the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html), especially the [section describing the state machine](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Parser-States).